# Version with 1.5 to run on device with version 2.1

Tags: android

I am developing android Applications and testing in on HTC magic (version 1.5). Will it bring any problem on running with higher version of Android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there are no problems with running older apps on newer platforms, since every new platform is backward-compatible.